# How to fix A message body reader for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart

Tags: java, ejb

How to solve above mentioned error. i run that through jboss 4 and java 1.6 version. and also i set content type in herder as multi part.

i have using `jercy bundle 1.19` jars. and `jax-rs-api2.21` jar

```
@POST
    @Path("/uploadDocument")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public String uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("attachment") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("attachment") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
try{}
catch(Exception e){}
}
```

> Error : A message body reader for Java class
>   com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and Java type class
>   com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and MIME media type
>   multipart/form-data